# How to do handle login-logoff

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the new user authentication system *Asp.Net Identity* in my project. I have a situation where I have to store 3 types of users in database i.e.:

- Student
- Teacher
- Admin

Now all these 3 have there separate table contains different information about each one of them. I want Asp.Net Identity to handle their login, logoff and password maintance for each type of user.

Can anyone please guide me with the overview of how can I handle this situation?

Comment: I think you need to use Custom MembershipProvider.

Comment: I believe you need to go with a membership provider. This can either be done with a custom membership provider or you can define 3 different roles in the asp .net membership schema.

Answer (score 1):

You need an inheritance structure like this:

```
public abstract class User {}
public class Student : User {}
public class Teacher : User {}
public class Admin : User {}
```

where the `User` base class holds all necessary info for authentication. This way, you can handle all types of Users in a unified way.

Regarding the database, there are various strategies how such polymorphism can be handled (e.g. *Table per Concrete Type*).

Comment: thanks, I have implemented your suggestion please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719067/is-this-approach-is-correct-in-mvc-5-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I just thought :

First of all, in your database make a table named "Roles", which will contains all your roles, as you mentioned in your post ( Student, Teacher, Admin and so on )

Then put a foreign key in your tables ( RoleId )

Make your `custom membership provider`

I think this should work